# Bluetooth Radio not reinstalling (Windows 10)

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-driver, windows-10-v20h1

I have a Samsung Spin 7 with Windows 10 Pro (updated to 20H1). Its got Intel AC8640. Wi-Fi is working correctly. Bluetooth is not installing.

The problem started when I noticed that Wi-Fi was getting disabled after Windows would wake up from Sleep Mode. It wouldn't connect after it woke up. So I had to disable the adapter and re-enable it. Recently, it was giving me additional problems while disabling and reenabling. It used to prompt me to restart the machine which was undesirable. To permanently fix the problem, I tried to update the AC8640 drivers from the Intel website. Now, I have the latest drivers installed from the Intel website version: 20.70.21.2. However, I noticed that Bluetooth was off. I tried to look for them in Device Manager, couldn't find them. Toggled "Show Hidden Devices" and voilà, Bluetooth was showing but dimmed out, like a disabled device appears. So, I uninstalled the device, thinking that a restart of the Windows will reinstall the drivers.

Nope. It didn't work.

So now I have no Bluetooth, can someone help?

I do have an Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Failed) showing up under Universal Serial Bus controllers section of the Device Manager. Does that have anything to do with Bluetooth by any chance?

Meanwhile, I have tried uninstalling my current Wi-Fi driver, reinstalling them with the Have Disk section - I remember I had drivers installed from Windows Update before I installed these Intel drivers - so I selected Intel AC 8640 (Microsoft) from the list that populates if you try to add a Legacy Hardware from Device Manager and select Network Adapters from the next popup.

I have also ran a sfc /scannow on my Windows10 before installing the Intel drivers - which found some corruptions and it said it fixed them.

dism /check said all was clean.

I am afraid, the Bluetooth hardware is fried or something - how would I check?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to the problem, accidentally.

1. Typed MSConfig in the Search window on Windows 10 UI
2. Selected Normal Startup and rebooted.
3. Next thing I know, my bluetooth speaker automatically connected at the next boot up
4. Installed latest Bluetooth drivers using Intel Driver Support Assistant
5. In deed, the USB device showing up with an error was the the Bluetooth device. Once the system booted correctly, the USB faulty device was no more.